# How to read the selected drop down list value from a cell in an Excel file using NPOI?

Tags: c#, excel, dropdown, npoi

I have an Excel file (xls) which contains a series of drop down lists in column F on the first sheet.  Each drop down list contains more than 7 options, which are all strings.  Each row has a different value selected.  Below is how the drop down lists were originally created using Microsoft.Office.Interop:

```
Application xlApp = new ApplicationClass();
Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range dropDownRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("F" + index, misValue);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns dropDowns = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns)xlWorkSheet.DropDowns(misValue);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown dropDown = dropDowns.Add((double)dropDownRange.Left, (double)dropDownRange.Top, (double)dropDownRange.Width, (double)dropDownRange.Height, true);
string[] currency = Config.listofCurrency();
for (int i = 0; i < currency.Length; i++)
{
    dropDown.AddItem(currency[i], i + 1);
    if (currency[i].ToLower() == defaultCurrency.ToLower())
    {
        dropDown.set_Selected(i + 1, misValue);
    }
}
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("F" + index, misValue).set_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, dropDown);
```

Now I am trying to read the file using NPOI to get the values of the cells in column F from the same file.  Here is the code I am using:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("excel.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    HSSFWorkbook hSSFWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileStream);
    ISheet isheet = hSSFWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
    IRow currentRow;
    for (int rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= isheet.LastRowNum; rowNumber++)
    {
        currentRow = isheet.GetRow(rowNumber);
        ICell cell = currentRow.GetCell(5);
        Console.WriteLine(currentRow.GetCell(5).ToString());
    }
}
```

But instead of string values, I am finding that the cell types are all numeric, and are all set to the value `7` which doesn't relate to the selected values in the dropdowns.

How can I get the correct values of the cells in NPOI?

Tested using EPPLus and ClosedXML, both give me 7s.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem, but unfortunately I don't have a solution for you.  It looks like this might be a bug in NPOI.

Comment: @BrianRogers tested using EPPlus, same thing, give me 7s. So I don't think it's a bug, unless both of them have the same bug.

Comment: Hmm.  It sounds like there really is a numeric 7 stored in the cell then (for whatever reason), and the dropdown information (including the selected item) is stored somewhere else.  It's entirely possible that none of these libraries have a means to extract that information.  I couldn't find a way to do it with NPOI or EPPlus.

Comment: Well, I've discovered something. Drop down controls in Excel have no relationship to specific cells! They might exactly cover a cell, but you can still set the cell value independently. You can see this for yourself if you put the Excel cursor on a cell that does not have a drop down list covering it, then use the keyboard to move the cursor to the covered cell. The cursor disappears behind the drop down. Then, try typing a value. That value is entered into the cell--you can see it in the formula bar--not in the drop down.

Comment: Guess these libraries don't support control then.

Comment: I'm guessing not.

Comment: I found out that if I use data validation instead of drop down control to create the excel, the cell will register the value selected.